# Where to pass back message when Model cannot find a record in DB in MVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wondering what is the best message to pass back the success or failure message from the model to the controller? The success message is easy because we can pass the data back. However, for failures, we can only pass FALSE and not the callback result of the failure.

What is the best method?

Here is method one:

Here is the model:

```
function get_pkg_length_by_id($data) {
    $this->db->where('id', $data['pkg_length_id']);
    $result = $this->db->get('pkg_lengths');
    if($result->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $result->row();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the controller, I will do

```
function show() {
    if(get_pkg_length_by_id($data) { 
        //pass success message to view
    }
    else {
        //Pass failure message to view
    }
```

Here is version 2:

In Model

```
function get_pkg_length_by_id($data) {
    $this->db->where('id', $data['pkg_length_id']);
    $result = $this->db->get('pkg_lengths');
    if($result->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        $result['status'] = array(
            'status' => '1',
            'status_msg' => 'Record found'
        );
        return $result->row();
    }
    else {
        $result['status'] = array(
            'status' => '0',
            'status_msg' => 'cannot find any record.'
        );
        return $result->row();
    }
}
```

In Controller

```
function show() {
$result = get_pkg_length_by_id($data);
    if($result['status['status']] == 1) { 
        //pass $result['status'['status_msg']] to view
    }
    else {
        //pass $result['status'['status_msg']] to view
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for certain which is best. I can say that I often use choice # 2, where I pass errors from the server, often doing so in a specific form that any subclass of my controller can parse and send to the view.

Also, in your show() function, the `else` is extraneous, once you return, you will break out of the function , so you can just do :

```
if($result->num_rows() > 0 ) {
    $result['status'] = array(
        'status' => '1',
        'status_msg' => 'Record found'
    );
   //the condition is met, this will break out of the function
    return $result->row();
}
$result['status'] = array(
  'status' => '0',
   'status_msg' => 'cannot find any record.'
);
return $result->row();
```

Comment: I think that the show function should just return once.  Using multiple returns => spaghetti code...  it would be best to set a variable in the if/else and return that.  Personal preference I suppose...

Comment: @joe42 yes, it is a matter of personal preference. Although I find that having a bunch of else's makes things more spaghetti code-like :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its always a good practice to do these kind of stuffs in model page.

I have made few changes on what you have done as follows:

```
function get_pkg_length_by_id($data) 
{
    $this->db->where('id', $data['pkg_length_id']);
    $query = $this->db->get('pkg_lengths');
    /*
        Just changed var name from $result to $query
        since we have a $result var name as return var
    */
    if($result->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        $result = $query->row_array();
        /*
            $result holds the result array.
        */
        $result['status'] = array(
            'status' => '1',
            'status_msg' => 'Record found'
        );
        //return $result->row();
        /*
          This will return $result->row() only which 
          doesn't include your $result['status']
        */
    }
    else {
        $result['status'] = array(
            'status' => '0',
            'status_msg' => 'cannot find any record.'
        );
        //return $result->row();
        /*
        This is not required.
        Returning just status message is enough.
        */
    }
    return $result;
}
```